# Android Custom ProgressBar not Rotating

Tags: android, animation, rotation, progress-bar

I want to change the default animation of a `ProgressBar`, so I added a custom style in my theme:

## styles.xml

```
<style name="ProgressTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/spinner_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

I am calling this style inside my `ProgressBar` with the following:

## ProgressBar.xml

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loadingProgressBar"
    style="@style/ProgressTheme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The problem lies inside the `spinner_holo_light.xml`:

If I use the following, everything works fine on devices with os 3.0+, but the progress does not rotate on older os versions:

## spinner_holo_light.xml

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_76_inner_holo"
    android:fromDegrees="720"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="0" />
```

But if I use `animate-rotate` instead, the animation works on every os version, but the result is a very laggy animation.

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_76_inner_holo"
    android:fromDegrees="720"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="0" />
```

What do you think about it? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On older devices it is a problem when `android:fromDegrees` is bigger than `android:toDegress` in `<rotate>`. Try swapping the values:

```xml
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_76_inner_holo"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="720" />
```

Alternatively, you can try setting it as infinite:

```xml
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_76_inner_holo"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite" />
```

The animation might be laggy on older devices. To fix this add `android:animationResolution` to the style:

```xml
<style name="ProgressTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/spinner_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:animationResolution">33</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Well thanks, I would never had figured this out. It work quite well now.

Answer (score 1):

Make transparent background of progress dialog.

Make border less progress dialog.

And customization of color of spinner of circular progress dialog.

http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/customization-of-spinner-progress/

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it work on Samsung Galaxy S Plus even adding

```
<item name="android:animationResolution">33</item>
```

I was asking something similar to your response @Tomik

[Android Progress Bar slow rotation on pre HoneyComb devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633319/android-progress-bar-slow-rotation-on-pre-honeycomb-devices/16633402?noredirect=1#16633402)

Is it smoothly on all the pre honeycomb devices for sure?

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this Problem by Changing BackGround xml Custom format to indeterminateDrawable

> Use **android:indeterminateDrawable** except **android:BackGround**

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
    android:layout_centerVertical = "true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateDrawable = "@drawable/progressbar"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"        
    android:indeterminate = "true"/>
```

And Custom Progressbar XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

 <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360">

     <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="7" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />
           <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:endColor="#00FF00"
            android:angle="0" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```