# Android Progress Bar slow rotation on pre HoneyComb devices

Tags: android, animation, rotation, progress-bar, drawable

I've been trying to achieve an smooth rotation of a drawer in pre honeycomb devices, but it was impossible for me:

In my layout.xml

```
<ProgressBar
    style="@style/ProgressBarLarge"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

in styles.xml

```
<!-- ProgressBar style -->
<style name="ProgressBarLarge" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/large_size</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/large_size</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_large</item>
</style>
```

and finally, here is my drawable:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_green_76"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="720" />
```

It works smoothy on Api 11 + devices, but on pre... it gets barred or slowly...

I'm desperate, I've tried to change the rotate drawer, change drawable resource to the right api version, but I couldn't get anything

Comment: There's probably something heavy being processed on your GUI thread. By the way, what are the devices you tested on?

Comment: There is nothing being processed on my GUI thread, because it's an splash activity with runnable timing. Everything works on separate thread. Moreover, In previously projects it happened the same so...

The device tested is Galaxy S Plus

Comment: I even tried to do this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332693/android-custom-progressbar-not-rotating
but nothing :-(

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the processing of every image, you can pre-process them on your computer, and then use a [Frame animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame):

> An animation defined in XML that shows a sequence of images in order
>   (like a film).

Comment: I wouldn't like to use animation, because I have to set it up programmatically... :S